# AgnualrJs - the difference of $parsers.unshift vs. $parsers.push

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the exact difference between `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift` and `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push` in custom directive.

I want to force angular to validate the form when something happens which takes effect on `model` but not the `form` itself. I tried to set `Form.$setSubmitted` but I know that it's not the way should be done. after a couple of googlings I found out that must use something like `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift` in my custom validation directive.

my directive has a duty to check the length of an array bound to `ng-model`:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                // doesn't enter this function at all!
                console.log(viewValue);
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$validators.requiredCount = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                // executed at the first time only at initialize
                return modelValue.length == attrs.requiredCount;
            };
        }
    };
```

and how i use it:

```
<list orientation="vertical" type="PropertyValue" ng-model="Entity.PropertyValues" 
          dont-save 
          ng-required="PropertyTypeIdObject.Code === 'FixedValues'"
          required-count="1"></list>
```

the `list` itself is a directive responsible for handling an array bound to `ng-model`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Parsers documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) `parsers` are an `Array of functions`

> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control
>   updates the ngModelController with a new $viewValue from the DOM,
>   usually via user input. See $setViewValue() for a detailed lifecycle
>   explanation. Note that the $parsers are not called when the bound
>   ngModel expression changes programmatically.
>
> The functions are called in array order, each passing its return value
>   through to the next. The last return value is forwarded to the
>   $validators collection.

so, in your code

```
 ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
      // doesn't enter this function at all!
      console.log(viewValue);
 });
```

You are pushing a new `function` to array of `parsers` to validate the `ngModel controller`

**Now, the difference between `unshift` and `push`:**

> 1. `Unshift` and `shift` make the whole array shift `sideways` (by
>      adding and removing items from the beginning)
> 2. `Push` and `pop` do NOT make the array shift sideways (because they
>      add and remove items at the end)

So, `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift` `insert` your function to `first index` and `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push` will `insert` your function to `last index`

Comment: and hence, `unshift` causes a parser to executed first in the pipeline, whereas `push` causes it to execute last in order.

Answer (score 2):

The Unshift and Push function is not unique to AngularJS and is a vanilla Javascript function.

The difference between unshift and push is that unshift pre-appends it to an array (which in this case will make sure the functions runs first) where as push adds it to an array (allowing everything else within the $parsers array to run before your validation. In this particular case it’s best practise to use unshift so that the validation takes place first before anything else.

Note: $parsers is just a regular javascript array, it’s not actually distinctive to angularJS. It inherits from array.prototype.

Let’s have an array of A B C D

For example for unshift(“X”) 
The array would output X A B C D

For example for push(“X”)
The array would output A B C D X